# How to revert to previous commit by ID

Tags: git

I have a commit id of "a9a6de2" within my list of commits that's a few versions old.

What's the git command to revert to that commit?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you mean revert the changes introduced by that commit, or check that commit out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to a previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Comment: I want my version of that project to match that previous commit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to revert that commit

`$ git revert a9a6de2` should do it

Comment: Had to stash first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to create a new branch that matches that SHA

```
git checkout -b YOUR_BRANCH a9a6de2
```

To make the currently checked out branch match that sha 
--Not working directory safe 
--Do not to to push this to a remote server

```
git reset --hard a9a6de2
```

Note that `git revert` does a subtractive patch of the SHA specified (and only the SHA specified), which doesn't sound at all like what you want.  I understand this is a common source of confusion for Subversion users because 'revert' behaves differently in Subversion.